# Data type sql database

Tags: ssms

I have a sql database and are trying to get the datatype of a column

Database: "dbo.Parts"
Table: "miniParts"

I tried the following using Microsoft SSMS

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE
   TABLE_NAME = "miniPARTS" AND COLUMN_NAME = "Date"
```

I get the following errors:

Invalid column name "dbo.PARTS"
Invalid column name "Date"

any ideas??

Comment: you should use single quote   'Date'

Comment: In MySQL? Or Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       DATA_TYPE, 
       IS_NULLABLE, 
       CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
       NUMERIC_PRECISION, 
       NUMERIC_SCALE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name';
```